# Spring security spring boot 4.x

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot

I am stuck at an issue here. I am using spring boot with primefaces for my application. I am using spring security for authentication. Somehow I am getting access denied. Addition to it the users are already established in the mongodb and if i use spring redirection everything works great.

```
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**").access("permitAll")
            .antMatchers("/logout**").access("permitAll")
            .antMatchers("/secure/homePage.xhtml").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('USER')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/secure/homePage.xhtml")
            .failureUrl("/login.xhtml?error").usernameParameter("email").and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout.xhtml")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml").invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true).and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied.xhtml");
```

Btw, I have the following in my login page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Comment: suppose you refer this [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-method-security) projects on github. they may have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is something fishy about your end points.

They are `/secure/homePage.xhtml`. These are usually pointing to a controller method and in the controller you supply the path to the view. then a specific view resolver will go and deliver the page.

```
@Bean
ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF");
    resolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");
    return resolver;

}


@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public String helloWorld(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

In this example, you will have a `helloWorld.xhtml` in `/WEB-INF/`